# jQuery Datatables - Custom Element in Datatable <td> with Flat array data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am trying to create a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) with [Flat array data source](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html).

So, my data returned from server is -

```
    {  
        "draw":5,
        "recordsTotal":57,
        "recordsFiltered":57,
        "data":[  
            {  
                "employee_name":"Airi Satou",
                "employee_salary":"162700",
                "employee_position":"Accountant",
                "employee_city":"Tokyo",
                "employee_extension":"5407",
                "employee_joining_date":"2008-11-27",
                "employee_age":"33",
                "id":1285
            },
            {  
                "employee_name":"Angelica Ramos",
                "employee_salary":"1200000",
                "employee_position":"Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
                "employee_city":"London",
                "employee_extension":"5797",
                "employee_joining_date":"2009-10-08",
                "employee_age":"47",
                "id":22874
            },
            {  
                "employee_name":"Ashton Cox",
                "employee_salary":"86000",
                "employee_position":"Junior Technical Author",
                "employee_city":"San Francisco",
                "employee_extension":"1562",
                "employee_joining_date":"2009-01-11",
                "employee_age":"66",
                "id":10123
            },
            {  
                "employee_name":"Bradley Greer",
                "employee_salary":"132000",
                "employee_position":"Software Engineer",
                "employee_city":"London",
                "employee_extension":"2558",
                "employee_joining_date":"2012-10-12",
                "employee_age":"41",
                "id":24680
            },
            {  
                "employee_name":"Brenden Wagner",
                "employee_salary":"206850",
                "employee_position":"Software Engineer",
                "employee_city":"San Francisco",
                "employee_extension":"1314",
                "employee_joining_date":"2011-06-06",
                "employee_age":"28",
                "id":27777
            }
        ]
    }
```

And My JS is -

```
    //Applied on Table with ID = "employee-grid"

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable(
        {
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,           //For Enabling AJAX
            "deferRender": true,        //For Speed up procesing time
            "ajax":
            {
                "url": "employee-grid-data.php",
                "type": 'POST',
                "data": function ( d )              //Sending Custom Data for manupulating with elements out of the table
                        {
                            d.StartDate =   "12-13-14";
                            d.EndDate   =   "Fuck You";
                            d.StateID   =   123;
                            // d.custom = $('#myInput').val();
                            // etc
                        },
                "error": function()                                 //Custom Error Function
                        {                                   // error handling
                            $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                            $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                            $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                        }
            },
            "columns":  [               //Name should be same as PHP file JSON NAmes and ordering should be as in the HTML file
                            {   "data": "employee_name"         },
                            {   "data": "employee_salary"       },
                            {   "data": "employee_position"     },
                            {   "data": "employee_city"         },
                            {   "data": "employee_extension"    },
                            {   "data": "employee_joining_date" },
                            {   "data": "employee_age"          },
                            {   "data": "id"                    }
                        ],
            "columnDefs":   [                               //For Action Buttons (Edit and Delete button) adding in the Action Column
                                {
                                    "orderable": false,     //Turn off ordering
                                    "searchable": false,    //Turn off searching
                                    "targets": -1,          //Going to last column
                                    "data": null,           //Not receiving any data
                                    "defaultContent": '<div style="min-width:70px" class="btn-group" role="group"><button type="button" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>'
                                }
                            ],

        });

        $("#employee-grid_filter").css("display","none");  // hiding global search box

    });
```

And HTML is -

```
        <table id="employee-grid"  class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <!-- Problamatic Part -->
                <!-- <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                    <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
                    <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
                </tr> -->
                <!-- Problamatic Part - END -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Extension</th>
                    <th style="min-width: 110px;">Joining Date</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="0" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="1" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="2" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="3" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="4" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <td valign="middle"><input type="text" id="5" placeholder="Select Date" class="employee-search-input datepicker" readonly="readonly"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="6" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
                    <th><input type="hidden"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

I am getting output like this-

[image]

So no Button is added in the **Action Column**.

But I had overrided action column contents like this-

```
            "columnDefs":   [                               //For Action Buttons (Edit and Delete button) adding in the Action Column
                                {
                                    "orderable": false,     //Turn off ordering
                                    "searchable": false,    //Turn off searching
                                    "targets": -1,          //Going to last column
                                    "data": null,           //Not receiving any data
                                    "defaultContent": '<div style="min-width:70px" class="btn-group" role="group"><button type="button" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>'
                                }
                            ],
```

So, Button code was-

```
  <div style="min-width:70px" class="btn-group" role="group"><button type="button" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>
```

But Button is not showing, ID is showing.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/362u5qtk/1/)**

Your `columnDefs` should have targeted `8th` column instead of `-1` and you were retrieving 8 column details per record but had last column assigned for Actions and totally there were `7` and hence `8th` row used to get the `id`. So below are the changes on `JS` part as well as `html` part:

```
"columnDefs":   [             
           //For Action Buttons (Edit and Delete button) adding in the Action Column
                    {
                        "orderable": false,     //Turn off ordering
                        "searchable": false,    //Turn off searching
                        "targets": [8],         //Going to last column
                        "data": null,           //Not receiving any data
                        "defaultContent": '<div style="min-width:70px" class="btn-group" role="group"><button type="button" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></button><button type="button" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>'
                    }
                 ],
```

and the **HTML**

```
<tr>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Extension</th>
    <th style="min-width: 110px;">Joining Date</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>ID</th> <!--Add one more ID-->
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="0" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="1" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="2" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="3" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="4" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
    <td valign="middle"><input type="text" id="5" placeholder="Select Date" class="employee-search-input datepicker" readonly="readonly"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="6" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="7" placeholder="Search" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
    <th><input type="hidden"></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it is more flexible and worked for me. And even you can set dynamic ID's in Actions.

```
       var JSONData = JSON.parse(AjaxResponse);
       $.each(JSONData, function (i, item) {
           var $row = $('<tr/>');
           var Actions="here Will be your Actions HTML";
            $row.append('<td>' + item.EmployName+ '</td><td>' + item.Salary+ '</td><td>' + item.Position+ '</td><td>' + item.City+ '</td><td>' +Actions + '</td>');


         });

        if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable(#employee-grid"))
         ;
       else
          $(#employee-grid").DataTable({ "bInfo": false, "bPaginate": false, "bLengthChange": false, "autoWidth": false, "order": [[0, "desc"]], "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1] }] });
```